# What is the probability that the phone will ring (i.e., the first call will arrive) within the next $30$ minutes (i.e. within the next $1/2$ an hour)?

Tags: probability, exponential-distribution

Dan, Dominic, and Doug
are waiting together in the living room for their girlfriends, Sally, Shellie, and
Susanne, to call. Their waiting times (in hours) are independent Exponential
random variables, with parameters $2.1$, $3.7$, and $5.5$, respectively. What is the
probability that the phone will ring (i.e., the first call will arrive) within the
next $30$ minutes (i.e., within the next $1/2$ an hour)?

so $\lambda_1 = 1/126$  for Dan

$\lambda_2 = 1/222$ for Dominic

$\lambda_3 = 1/330$ for Doug

Let X represent Dan's waiting time. Y represent Dominic's waiting time. Z represent Doug's waiting time.

$P(X\leq30) = 1 -e^{-30/126}$

$P(Y\leq30) = 1 -e^{-30/222}$

$P(Z\leq30) = 1 -e^{-30/330}$

so $P(min (X,Y,Z) \leq 30) = ???$

I don't know what to do in this last step. The final answer is  $0.9965$ But how did they get that answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's consider two independent exponential random variables, each with a different rate parameter, say $X \sim \operatorname{Exponential}(\lambda)$, $Y \sim \operatorname{Exponential}(\theta)$, with $$F_X(x) = 1 - e^{-\lambda x}, \quad F_Y(y) = 1 - e^{-\theta y}.$$  We construct a new random variable $Z = \min(X,Y)$.  How is $Z$ distributed?  We note $$\Pr[Z > z] = \Pr[\min(X,Y) > z] = \Pr[(X > z) \cap (Y > z)] \overset{\text{ind}}{=} \Pr[X > z]\Pr[Y > z] = e^{-\lambda z} e^{-\theta z} = e^{-(\lambda + \theta)z}.$$  Hence $$F_Z(z) = \Pr[Z \le z] = 1 - \Pr[Z > z] = 1 - e^{-(\lambda + \theta)z},$$ meaning $Z = \min(X,Y)$ is exponential with rate $\lambda + \theta$, the sum of the rates of $X$ and $Y$.  So if we have three independent exponential random variables, the minimum of these waiting times will also be exponential with rate equal to the sum of the individual rates.

Applying this to the question, we then have the probability that the first call to arrive being within the first $30$ minutes is simply $$\Pr[W = \min(X,Y,Z) \le 30] = 1 - e^{-(\lambda_1 + \lambda_2 + \lambda_3)30} = 1-e^{-0.464139} \approx 0.371324.$$  I do not get the claimed answer; it's too large.

Comment: YES I GET THE SAME THING as i wrote in one of the comments THANK YOU

Comment: Is it possible that I misinterpreted the lambda values. I think those are the averages per minute given proportionality (which is assumed for exponential distribution)?

Comment: @TobyRobuscus I even performed a simulation and got roughly the same answer.  We can also reason that the claimed answer must be incorrect because even if all three have the same mean waiting time of $2.1$ hours, that would suggest the first call to arrive will be exponentially distributed with a mean waiting time of $2.1/3 = 0.7$ hours, and the probability to have the first call arrive within half an hour is $1 - e^{-5/7} \approx 0.510458 < 0.9965$.  Since the other two boyfriends have even longer waiting times, the true probability is less than $0.510458$.

Comment: @TobyRobuscus Do you mean $2.1, 3.7, 5.5$ refer to the mean number of calls per hour?  In such a case, their girlfriends need to get a life and those guys need to block their numbers.  But under this (admittedly terrifying) assumption, I get $$1 - e^{-(11.3)(0.5)} \approx 0.996482.$$

Comment: Is that even the correct interpretation though? The answers match up, but isn't the $2.1,3.7,5.5$ the waiting time to get a call from a girl since it's exponential and not the average amount of calls per hour? Is this just really bad wording from the book I'm using?

Comment: The number $\mu_1=2.1$ is the mean interarrival time in hours between Sally's calls. Then $\lambda_1=1/126 =\frac{1}{60(2.1)}$ is the rate per minute at which Sally's calls arrive. We have both used that, and with that convention both of our answers are correct.

Comment: @TobyRobuscus I only performed the computation that way to show that under such an interpretation (i.e. that those numbers are calls per hour, rather than hours per call), you would get the claimed answer.  But it is implausible that any person, no matter how obsessed, would be calling someone on average $5.5$ times per hour, which is like calling once every $11$ minutes.  Consequently, I think your interpretation is correct and realistic and the "official" solution made the mistake of not taking reciprocals.

Answer (score 1):

**Derivation of minimum:**

$V = \min(X,Y,Z)$  Use the CDF method to find the distribution of $V.$

$$F_V(v) = P(V \le v) =  1 - P(V > v) \\
= 1 - P(X>v, Y>v, Z>v)\\ = 1 - P(X>v)P(Y>v)P(V>v) \\
= 1 - e^{-\lambda_1v}e^{-\lambda_2v}e^{-\lambda_3v}
= 1 - e^{-(\lambda_+\lambda_2+\lambda_3)v},$$
for $v > 0.$ We recognize this as the CDF of an
exponential distribution with rate $\lambda = \lambda_1+\lambda_2+\lambda_3.$

$P(V \le 30) = 1 - e^{-30\lambda} = 0.3713.$  Computation in R:

```
lam.1  = 1/126;  lam.2 = 1/222;  lam.3 = 1/330
lam = lam.1 + lam.2 + lam.3;  lam
[1] 0.01547132
1 - exp(-30*lam)
[1] 0.3713241
pexp(30, lam)  3 'pexp' is exponential CDF
[1] 0.3713241
```

**Simulation:**

set.seed(2021)
lam.1  = 1/126;  lam.2 = 1/222;  lam.3 = 1/330
# rates per min
x = rexp(10^6, lam.1)
y = rexp(10^6, lam.2)
z = rexp(10^6, lam.3)
v = pmin(x,y,z)
mean( v <= 30)
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNgz4.png) 0.629108
2*sd(v <= 30)/1000
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNgz4.png) 0.0009660877

```
mean(v <= 30)
[1] 0.370892
2*sd(v <= 30)/1000
[1] 0.0009660877
```

So the probability of a call in the next half hour
is $P(V \le 30) \approx 0.371 \pm 0.001.$

```
hdr = 
 "Histogram of Simulated Dist'n of V 
with Density of EXP(rate=0.0155)"
hist(v, prob=T, br=50, col="skyblue2", main=hdr)
 curve(dexp(x, 0.0155), add=T, col="red", lwd=2)
 abline(v = 30, col="darkgreen", lwd=2, lty="dotted")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hint : you need to find $P(X\leq30  \cup Y\leq30  \cup Z\leq30 )$

Comment: When I do all that I just get $.3713$? I did $P(X \leq 30 \cdot Y \leq 30 \cdot Z \leq 30) + P (X \leq 30 \cdot Y \leq 30 \cdot Z \geq 30) + P (X \leq 30 \cdot Y \geq 30 \cdot Z \leq 30) + P (X \geq 30 \cdot Y \leq 30 \cdot Z \leq 30) + P( X \leq 30 \cdot Y \geq 30 \cdot Z \geq 30) + P( X \geq 30 \cdot Y \leq 30 \cdot Z \geq 30)+ P( X \geq 30 \cdot Y \geq 30 \cdot Z \leq 30)   = .3713$

Answer (score 0):

A much simpler approach.  The desired result is $1-Prob((X\ge30) \cap (Y\ge 30)\cap (Z\ge 30))=$$1-e^{-(30/126+30/222+30/330)}=.3713$

The final result uses independence.